# Only status 200 is good anything else is an error in angular $http?

Tags: angularjs, http, angular-promise

Quick question:

Angular $http returns a promise.   The promise can be a success, resolved object (status 200) or an error, reject object (status 404). Does that mean that anything that is not a status 200 response IN angular $http will be rejected and sent to the error part of the promise?  Example: 404,304,401, 500, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes by default. However, you can change that behaviour using interceptors, where you can choose what kind of promise execution to return, and that will modify the pipe to be executed in the original call.

[More info about interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

Answer (score 3):

Anything that begins with a 2xx is a successful response:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: In other words, yes. Anything other than a 2xx response code is an error as it well should be.

Comment: not asking about the http protocol I am asking specific how angular $http handles the http responses from a server.  What goes thru the "Success" pipe and what goes thru the "Error" pipe